# How to join 2 separate tables using HQL query

Tags: java, hibernate, hql

Need Hibernate query to join 2 distinct tables . 
ex:

```
private class User
{
    private long userid;
    private String name;

    //stters and getters
}
```

And onother table as

```
private class UserProfile
{
    private long id;
    private String company;

    //setters and getters
}
```

Here userid and id are the same constraints.

Please help in this regards
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

HQL uses entity names and entity property names. Never table or column names.

I suggest you read the documentation about HQL, and especially about joins and associations.
http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/4.3/manual/en-US/html/ch16.html#queryhql-joins

The query you need is:

```
select user.id, user.name, profile.id, profile.company from User as user
inner join user.UserProfile as profile
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I will try

Comment: But here why it is used as user.UserProfile ?

Comment: UserProfile is a different pojo not contained in User pojo.